# Having trouble publishing react application to iis - AggregateException & InvalidOperationException

Tags: reactjs, iis, .net-core

I am getting errors after I've published my website to a server and trying to reach it.
The application is built in Visual Studio using .core 3.1 - react.

Not sure what could cause this, but I am guessing it has to do something with the script build inside the package.json file.

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "production": "env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts build",
  },
```

startup.cs (I've tried using both `build` and `production` - but the same problem occur).

```
if (env.IsProduction())
{
      spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "build");
}
```

And the exception:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'build' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: ))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)

InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'build' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
```

AggregateExeption:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'build' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: ))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'build' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: ))
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'build' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: )
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'build' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: 
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.<>c.<Attach>b__2_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

InvalidOperationException:

```
InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'build' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)

Show raw exception details
System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'build' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: 
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
```

Since i am kinda new to React, if there is something I could do to debug this or any info that could help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClientApp` subdirectory is a standard  `React Application` based on the `Create-React-App` template. Therefore it depends on the `NPM command`. Try to update the `Nodejs` version by directly downloading it in the `NodeJs` official document.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Under certain circumstances, we have to clean up installed global modules as well.
Please check this link for more details.
https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/bcd221/using_my_own_packagejson_for_react_causes_aspnet/

Comment: Thanks will try this and get back to you. Is nodejs needed on the target server running IIS?

Comment: There is no need to install NodeJS on the server-side. As long as we ensure that the output files could be built properly in the production mode. @arkhz

Comment: I've downloaded latest nodejs, using ```"node": "^14.5.0",``` now in my project. But I am still getting the error when I publish. Seems like start is working, but the build/production is not.

Comment: Update: this did help me out - but for some reason, I was also needed to removed the ```spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "build");```.